# Calling all functors in a container

Tags: c++11

I have a sequence of std::function objects (a very primitive form of signal system). Is there a standard (in C++0x) function or functor that will call given std::function?  For now I use

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), 
              std::mem_fn(&std::function<void ()>::operator()));
```

IMHO this `std::mem_fn(&std::function<void ()>::operator())` is ugly.  I'd like to be able to write

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), funcall);
```

Is there such a `funcall`?  Alternativly I can implement a function

```
template<typename I>
void callInSequence(I from, I to)
{
  for (; from != to; ++from) (*from)();
}
```

Or may I have to use a signal/slot system, such as Boost::Signals, but I have a feeling that this is an overkill (I do not need multithreading support here, all `std::function`s are constructed using std::bind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any apply function. However, in C++0x you can use lambdas and write the following.

```
std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(),
    [](std::function<void ()> const & fn) { fn(); });
```

Alternatively, you can use the new for loop.

```
for (auto const & fn: c)
    fn();
```

Comment: That true, thanks. I have fogotten to note that I'm using Gcc 4.4 and it lack support for lambda expressions.  The second could easily emulated with Boost.Foreach and it seems quite clean.